# Howto use org.chromium.identity for native google connect in Cordova

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, cordova

I would like use native google plus sign feature for connect my phonegap/cordova application (android et IOS).
Usually in Phonegap we use InAppBrowser for include web popup. It's done but suppose the user log with email and password with web UI. So in Android, we used google play for that and the same for IOS.

In january, it's now possible to use Chrome Apps inside Cordova.
 http://blog.chromium.org/2014/01/run-chrome-apps-on-mobile-using-apache.html

Many cordova plugins are available and particulary chrome.identity : https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/tree/master/chrome-cordova/plugins/chrome.identity

How to use this plugin outside the ChromeApps for native google signIn ? 
I'm installed the plugins but none samples to access chrome object and Api.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

This is an old-ish question but I thought I should post my solution since I hit this tonight... below is how I used the plugin to authenticate and call a service API. Apologies if it's not that efficient, it's been a long night :P (this is built for now on the Cordova starter template)

```
var app = { 
onDeviceReady: function() {
    /*********************
    *   I attached an EventListener to a link so I kept this binding
    *   Helps when testing to have a link handy to revoke the token
    **********************/
    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');

    /****************************************************************************
    *   The documentation is a little odd here, but since this isn't
    *   a Chrome app, we need to set the Manifest JSON manually.
    *
    *   The scopes are to only modify and read a calendar, not sure I need both
    *   but what the hell...
    ****************************************************************************/
    chrome.runtime.setManifest({
      oauth2: {
         // ClientID obtained from the Developers Console
        client_id: clientID,
        scopes: [ 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly' ]
      }
    },function(){
        // callback for setMainfest, empty..
        });
    /***********************************************************************
    *   Because I don't have Google Play Services setup yet I have to use
    *   the 'interactive' mode which will prompt the user to select the account,
    *   then show a permission screen. 
    *
    *   I have multiple (Google) accounts on my phone so I set the 'accountHint'
    *   to try to force authenticating my primary account and avoid having to deal
    *   with a popup.
    ******************************************************************************/
    // Just checking if I already have grabbed it, if so, no need to do it again
    if(!bToken){
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken(
            { 
                'interactive': true,
                'accountHint':  ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
            }, 
            function(token, acct) {
                // set a global variable or debug...
            });
        }
},
}
var calendar = {
list: function(token) {
    // Simple AJAX call, passing the token through and dealing with the results...
    // This function just pulls calendar info...
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: listURL,
        data: encodeURI("access_token="+token),
        cache: false,
        success:function(result) {
            // do something....
        }
    })
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!